# Add a class to div only if specific input button in clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a function that displays a hidden div for error messaging in a form.

For this function, I need the div to display in 2 different spots depending on the scenario. So I need to add a class if a specific submit button is clicked. I could write a separate function, but I would like to include it within my current function that handles the display of the div:

```
function giftAlert(){
    var args = arguments;
    if(args.length > 1) {
        // check that custom alert was called with at least two arguments
        var msg = args[0];
        $('.errorPopup').hide();
      $('.couponPopup').hide();
      $('.promotionPopup').hide();
    $("*").removeClass("alertRed");
        $("*").removeClass("CO_form_alert");


        var div = $(".giftPopup");
        div.css({"display":"block"});
        if (div.length == 0) {
            div = $("<div class='giftPopup' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
            $("body").prepend(div);
        }
       div.html(msg);
        for(var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            var inputID = args[i];
           $("#"+inputID).addClass("CO_form_alert").parent().addClass("alertRed");
       $('#' + inputID).focus();
       $('#' + inputID).keydown(function() { $('.giftPopup').hide(); }).change(function() { $('.giftPopup').hide(); }).blur(function() { $('.giftPopup').hide(); });

        }
     }

}
```

So where this bit is:

```
var div = $(".giftPopup");
            div.css({"display":"block"});
```

I would like to add some logic, if input1 is clicked then giftPopup gets an additional class, but only for input1.

help?

Comment: Where do you define those two inputs and/or add click handlers to them? Add the code there. `onclick="if (this.id = 'input1') { add class to popup };"` kinda thing.

Comment: I'd avoid using onclick=... in favor of using jquery's .click() or even better is to use .live();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input1 element is made up of the html `<input class="input1" type=button />`, all you need to do in jQuery is:

```
$('.input1').click(function(){
    $('.giftPopup').addClass('whatever');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/Dsb8X/

Answer (score 1):

I would just bind a click to the input1.  Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7fHV/1/) that does some things that should be very helpful for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input1").live("click", function() {
        $(".giftPopup").addClass("special");
    });
});
```

Unless you have a very good reason to use onclick you should use jquery to bind the events using .live() or .delegate().  You could also use .click() in this case but when you're messing around adding elements to the DOM, you have to use .live() or .delegate() because .click() won't work on elements added to the DOM later.

Comment: I actually don't want it to work on elements added later. I want the change to be a one time change, only when the button is clicked.

Comment: great answer though. I realize that normally, you are supposed to avoid click

Comment: Using .live() or .delegate() never hurts.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `for` loop in your code as below. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
       for(var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
           var inputID = args[i];
           var $input = $("#"+inputID);
           $input.addClass("CO_form_alert").parent().addClass("alertRed");
           $input.focus().keydown(function() { $('.giftPopup').hide(); }).change(function() { $('.giftPopup').hide(); }).blur(function() { $('.giftPopup').hide(); });

           if(i == 1){
              $input.click(function(){
                 $(".giftPopup").addClass("specifyClassNameHere");
              });
           }
        }
```

Comment: I have to say that usually your answers are fantastic, but this one I just don't agree with.  I just can't see how modifying the code above instead of leveraging the power of jquery is a good way to go.